# Actionscript3 / LCCS: how to access property parent class protected var?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop, inheritance, actionscript

I would like to assign an event listener to a protected timer variable in the parent class.

I am working with Adobe LCCS, and created a [BatonProperty](http://livedocs.adobe.com/labs/acrobatcom/index.html?com/adobe/rtc/sharedModel/BatonProperty.html&com/adobe/rtc/sharedModel/class-list.html) 
which implements [Baton](http://livedocs.adobe.com/labs/acrobatcom/index.html?com/adobe/rtc/sharedModel/Baton.html&com/adobe/rtc/sharedModel/class-list.html)

Now, Baton has a protected timer variable declared like this, and for some reason, I am unable to get access to this _autoPutDownTimer, from a BatonProperty instance.

```
  public function Baton()
          {
              super();

              _autoPutDownTimer = new Timer(_timeout*1000, 1);
              _autoPutDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
              invalidator.addEventListener(Invalidator.INVALIDATION_COMPLETE,commitP roperties);
          }
```

I would love to attach an eventlistener to it like this, but it seems I cannot, any tips are truly appreciated:

```
    public var mybatonprop:BatonProperty;
    mybatonprop= new BatonProperty();
    mybatonprop.sharedID = "myBaton";
    mybatonprop.subscribe();

    mybatonprop.baton._autoPutDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,countDown);
```

This gives the error : "actionscript attempted access of inaccessible property through a reference with static type" But it seems that property is not private, only protected, since it is declared like this

```
    /**
     * @private
     */
    protected var _autoPutDownTimer:Timer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `BatonProperty` extends `Baton`, then just change the line:

```
mybatonprop.baton._autoPutDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,countDown);
```

to

```
mybatonprop._autoPutDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,countDown);
```

otherwise, make `_autoPutDownTimer` public, or follow @Jacob's answer.

Or for a third suggestion, as `Baton` is an Adobe class and you can't edit it, create your own class `MyBaton` which extends `Baton`, then do either of the two suggestions. (`MyBaton` will work everywhere `Baton` does)

Comment: +1 for your third suggestion.  That is the solution in this case since editing the Baton and BatonProperty classes is out of the question.

Comment: Thanks divilysausages, I tried your first suggestion: Type
1119: Access of possibly undefined property _autoPutDownTimer through a reference with static type com.adobe.rtc.sharedModel:BatonProperty. I think this is because BatonProperty does not inherit Baton but uses it via composition as Jacob mentioned. I could create my own classes, but for now I put in a feature request for Adobe to expose this functionality.
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/892491?tstart=0

Comment: yeah, that error's from composition vs inheritance. Btw, if you have the source code from the Adobe classes, provided the license is alright, it should be fine to modify them

Answer (score 2):

`protected` means private except to descendants of the class. i.e. classes that inherit from the parent. It looks like your BatonProperty uses Baton via composition, not inheritance. And, from what I can tell, it seems like you're trying to access the _autoPutDownTimer from Baton/BatonProperty via a third class.

My recommendation, though would not be to add the event listener directly to the timer, but to dispatch an event from `Baton` in the `onTimerComplete` function

```
protected function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
    ....
    dispatchEvent(new Event('putDownComplete'));
}
```

and

```
mybatonprop.baton.addEventListener('putDownComplete', onPutdownComplete);
```

Comment: Much appreciated Jacob, couple questions: 1. In order to add that event it seems like you recommend modifying the parent class, but these are provided by Adobe in swc files. Is it ok, if I modify these files in my project? 2. I am really after the actual timer not the end event, since I would like to show the remaining time to users. What I had in mind was add this `_autoPutDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,countDown); ` inside the Baton class public function, so in my countDown function I can get `_autoPutDownTimer.currentCount`

Comment: 1. Yes it's okay to modify the classes in your swc, though you could also extend them instead. 2. `TimerEvent.Timer` and `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` are basically equivalent for this case because the count on timer is 1 (`_autoPutDownTimer = new Timer(_timeout*1000, >>1<<);`)